# where can I get the source code for "setfacl" Linux/Unix command

Tags: linux, unix, command

The `SETFACL` utility sets Access Control Lists (ACLs) of files and directories.

I need to understand the source code of `setfacl` command. Can some one please let me know where can I get it?

Comment: http://savannah.nongnu.org/git/?group=acl

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can download [here](http://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/acl.git/snapshot/acl-2.2.53.tar.gz)

**2020 Edit:** Link is updated

Comment: Until that version gets obsoleted and drops out of the archive

Comment: I have referred it in order to get information main logic of setfacl programatically. I prefer to see man pages and product web sites to source code.

Comment: 404 at that address D`: